# Associate my public cv with my SO account

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, jobs

I like how I can associate my SO and other accounts with my public CV. Can there be a field added to my SO profile that links to my public CV? I know I could add it to the free text description, but this feels like something that should be baked in.

Edit: Maybe implement this with a "Add my public CV to my StackOverflow profile" checkbox on the "make your cv public" screen.

Answer (score 3):

I could see this as an option, but not as a required element.  Many people don't want their CV publicized due to the possibilty of recruiters getting access to it and using it to market you (or simply annoy you) without your consent.

Answer (score 1):

Good suggestion/feature request.  However, "automatic" type of features are not well recieved in most cases.  They can be options, but most things should not be automatic. Most users I have seen here like options, but not forced/auto type of things.

Comment: Fixed. Removed automatic. It was misleading.